# Wrong View Height when using inputAccessoryView with External (blue tuth) keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, keyboard, uitextfield

In my application i have set `inputAccessoryView` to the textfield.

While i use Bluetooth keyboard it's giving me wrong height of view, Its subtracting device's keyboard height from the total iPad height `1024` in spite of keyboard is not displayed in device, as Bluetooth keyboard is ON.

If I don't set `inputAccessoryView` Or set it nil than it's working fine and giving me correct height `1024` of the view.

can one guide me please where i am wrong or if anything missing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for us on iPad. Could you please check if you have similar parameters for below methods,

```
inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

and

when we force keyboard,

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
Global *obj=[Global getInstance];
inputAccessoryView.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 420, screenHeight, 352);
```